# Recyclerview adapter not returning correct visibility

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have an issue with my recyclerview.
Basically, its adapter is a sortedlist, and when a certain criteria is met, a colored tick appears on the left of the item's name.

My issue is, this tick sometimes randomly appears on items it shouldn't appear on. Usually when i scroll down the list, then back up to the top.

[RecyclerView with the correct ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDpfM.png)

[After i scroll down and back up, the second item gets the tick, although it shouldn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Raw27.png)

This is the adapter's onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) { 
[...]
SharedPreferences prefcorsi = contesto.getSharedPreferences(Costanti.ISCRIZIONECORSI,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences prefgruppi = contesto.getSharedPreferences(Costanti.ISCRIZIONEGRUPPI,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (evento.getIdgruppo() > 0 && prefgruppi.getInt(Integer.toString(evento.getIdgruppo()),0) > 0) {
        holder.checkiscritto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.w("Iscritto gruppo adapter",evento.getTitolo());
    } else if (prefcorsi.getInt(Integer.toString(evento.getId()),0) > 0 && evento.getStatoiscrizione() > 0) {
        holder.checkiscritto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.w("Iscritto da adapter",evento.getTitolo());
    }
```

I'm 100% sure it's not an issue somewhere else, since 
1) the Log.w doesn't show the faulty item, the tick just appears by its side.
2) Sharedpreferences and object's getter return the right values.

Could it be a bug, or maybe too many items to be processed?

Comment: You need to explicitly set the visibility to `GONE`/`INVISIBLE` when the `if` conditions are both false; that is, in a final `else`.

Comment: Your viewholder is not using the `position` parameter, which seems suspicious...

Comment: @MikeM. thank you, correct answer.